# Replace characters in string by iterating over the characters

Tags: python, string, replace

```
x = ['"yes',
 '3',
 '""McGowan Miss. Anna """"Annie""""""',
 'female#',
 '15',
 '8.0292"']

for string in x:
    for character in string:
        character = character.replace('"','')
x
```

gives

```
['"yes',
 '3',
 '""McGowan Miss. Anna """"Annie""""""',
 'female#',
 '15',
 '8.0292"']
```

and I don't know why its not removing the " from the strings...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

how would I iterate through a List of List?

```
x = [['"yes',
 '3',
 '""McGowan Miss. Anna """"Annie""""""',
 'female#',
 '15',
 '8.0292"'],[True,
  1,
  'Futrelle Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)',
  'female',
  '35',
  '53.1']]
```

with

```
for i in x:
    for b in i:
        b[i] = b[i].replace('"', '')
```

doesnt work...

EDIT2:
fixed, my x had integers and booleans

Answer (score 3):

Replace you whole for loop with this:

```py
for i, string in enumerate(x):
    x[i] = string.replace('"','')
```

Comment: doesn't work for me... still gives me ['"yes',
 '3',
 '""McGowan Miss. Anna """"Annie""""""',
 'female#',
 '15',
 '8.0292"']

Comment: @Orsons Fixed the problem now

Comment: what would i have to do if x would be like that? x = [['"yes',
 '3',
 '""McGowan Miss. Anna """"Annie""""""',
 'female#',
 '15',
 '8.0292"'],[True,
  1,
  'Futrelle Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)',
  'female',
  '35',
  '53.1']]

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the `string`, not `character`.

```
x = ['"yes',
 '3',
 '""McGowan Miss. Anna """"Annie""""""',
 'female#',
 '15',
 '8.0292"']

for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] = x[i].replace('"', '')

print(x)
```